# What is main difference between Mock and Spy in Swift?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, mocking, spy

I was reading [this article](http://xunitpatterns.com/Mocks,%20Fakes,%20Stubs%20and%20Dummies.html) for studying Test Double. And I am really confused about difference between Mock and Spy in Swift.

As far as I know, I can use protocol or inheritance to make Mock or Spy for test, and both capture indirect output. The difference is Mock can verify **itself** through like `verify()`. This is the point where I am confused now. Because most example about Mock in Swift don't verify itself but just use `XCTAssertXXX()` **in Test class**, and I know I can't use `verify()` without 3rd party library.

In this situation, it seems like there is no difference between Mock and Spy.

Am I missing something? Just let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: A mock completely replaces a type while a spy only partially replaces it. Not sure what verify() has to do with this, isn't it rather implementation specific for a mocking framework rather than being part of the definition of mocking and/or spying? And is there a real use case behind this question or is it only a theoretical one?

Comment: Hello @JoakimDanielson
It was just a theoretical question. And I thought when I use mock, I must use verify method(from framework or custom implementation like this page[https://saad-eloulladi.medium.com/unit-tests-swift-mocking-the-right-way-65488848a3fc ]) to assert. And this is the most important difference. Am I wrong?